# Edge Detection code for BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to create an Object that given an Image and Point it will trace the inside edge of that Image.

For simplicity the edges will always be of RGB Color Black.

i Define enums of RIGHT DOWN LEFT UP (Clockwise)

I start at Point p.

I move through the Pixels in the Image based on the current Direction starting with RIGHT.

if this is not a border Pixel i move my Direction back one step anti Clockwise. e.g (Left->DOWN)
 if i cannot move my chosen direction i move to next direction.
i add the Point to my border array.

i do this till we return to the first border Pixel.

Thats the Plan...

So far i hit a snag when i have to go from UP to RIGHT  but back to RIGHT again immediately after in order to keep the direction focused on the edge rather than turn back into the Image.

Ive tried using a boolean flag if UP is used, Directing the Next direction for right to be UP and Not DOWN.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.
I have the full Code below.

CODE:

```
package edgedection;

import static edgedection.EdgeDection.testImage;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

    /**
     *
     * @author Fionán
     */
    public class EdgeDection {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        static BufferedImage testImage = null;

        {
            try {
                testImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("testImage2.png"));

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EdgeDection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        static enum DIRECTION {

            RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT, UP, NOMOVE
        }

        BufferedImage bi;
        int borderColor = Color.black.getRGB();

        DIRECTION facing;
        Point p;
        ArrayList<Point> borders;
        boolean upFlag = false;
         int x = p.x;
         int y = p.y;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int x = 150;
            int y = 60;
    //forcing instance for loading Images only.
            EdgeDection test= new EdgeDection();

            JFrame show = new JFrame();
            show.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(testImage));
            show.add(picLabel);
            show.pack();

            show.setVisible(true);

            EdgeDection dector = new EdgeDection(testImage, new Point(x, y));
            dector.start();

            dector.highLightEdge();

            show.repaint();

        }

        boolean canMove(DIRECTION d, Point p) {

            switch (d) {
                case RIGHT:
                    return bi.getRGB(p.x + 1, p.y) != borderColor;
                case DOWN:
                    return bi.getRGB(p.x, p.y + 1) != borderColor;
                case LEFT:
                    return bi.getRGB(p.x - 1, p.y) != borderColor;
                //Deafult is up
                case UP:
                    return bi.getRGB(p.x, p.y - 1) != borderColor;
                default:
                    return false;

            }

        }

        public EdgeDection(BufferedImage bi, Point p) {
            this.facing = DIRECTION.RIGHT;
            this.bi = bi;
            this.p = p;
            this.borders = new ArrayList<>();

        }

        public EdgeDection() {
        }

        DIRECTION getDirection() {
            return null;
        }

        void addBorder(Point p) {
            if(borders.isEmpty()){

            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
            }
            borders.add(p);
        }

        void start() {

            do {

                System.out.println("Checking " + p.x + " " + p.y + facing);
                if (canMove(facing, p)) {


                    if (upFlag) {
                        facing = DIRECTION.UP;
                      //  p =new Point(p.x+1,p.y);
                    }
                    p = NextPointByDirection();


                    if(!upFlag) stepBackDirection();

                    if(upFlag)upFlag=false;


                } else {
                    addBorder(p);
                    setNextDirection();

                    System.out.println("going " + facing + " border array size = "+ borders.size());
                    System.out.println("Up Flag status "+upFlag);
                }

            } while (facing != DIRECTION.NOMOVE && (p.x != x || p.y != y));



        }

        private void stepBackDirection() {

            switch (facing) {

                case RIGHT:
                    if(upFlag) {facing = DIRECTION.UP;}else{
                    facing = DIRECTION.RIGHT;
                    }
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    facing = DIRECTION.RIGHT;
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    facing = DIRECTION.DOWN;

                    break;
                case UP:
                    facing = DIRECTION.LEFT;

            }
        }

        private void setNextDirection() {

            switch (facing) {
                case RIGHT:

                    facing = DIRECTION.DOWN;

                    if (upFlag) {
                        facing = DIRECTION.UP;
                        upFlag = false;
                    }
                    return;
                case DOWN:
                    facing = DIRECTION.LEFT;
                    return;
                case LEFT:
                    facing = DIRECTION.UP;
                    return;
                case UP:
                   upFlag = true;
                   facing = DIRECTION.RIGHT;

    //                upFlag = true;
    //                if (canMove(facing, new Point(p.x + 1, p.y - 1))){
    //                p = new Point(p.x + 1, p.y - 1);
    //                
    //                } ;
    //
    //                if (upFlag) {
    //                    facing = DIRECTION.RIGHT;
    //                }

            }
        }

        private Point NextPointByDirection() {
    //        if (upFlag) {
    //            facing = DIRECTION.UP;
    //            upFlag = !upFlag;
    //        }
            switch (facing) {
                case RIGHT:
                    return new Point(p.x + 1, p.y);
                case DOWN:
                    return new Point(p.x, p.y + 1);
                case LEFT:
                    return new Point(p.x - 1, p.y);

                default:
                    return new Point(p.x, p.y - 1);

            }
        }

        private void print() {

            for (Point p : borders) {

                System.out.print(p.x + " " + p.y + " ");

            }
        }

        void highLightEdge() {

            for (Point p : borders) {

                bi.setRGB(p.x, p.y, Color.RED.getRGB());

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested , i solved this problem with the use of a Stack.

pre-populate the stack with the order of directions to take.
Start moving in a direction.
if it can move direction is popped from stack
else
Hit a border
push that direction to the stack
add The border to the Set of borders
if border is already in set break loop else
turn 90 degree relative to the direction